# How to test throw within observable error

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

In our `app.component`, we use a subscription to detect websocket failure.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.subscriptions.push(
    this.ws.getData().subscribe(
      (message: any) => { },
      error => {
        this.isOverlayVisible = true;
      },
      () => console.info('Websocket completed'),
    ),
  );
```

We would like to test that `isOverlayVisible` is set to `true` when an error occurs.

Setup:

```
websocketDataSubject = new Subject();
ws = jasmine.createSpyObj('ws', ['getData']);
ws.getData.and.returnValue(websocketDataSubject);
```

Test:

```
describe('when error is received', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    component.isOverlayVisible = false;
    websocketDataSubject.error('any error');
  });

  it('should set isOverlayVisible to true', () => {
    expect(component.isOverlayVisible).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

but since an actual error is thrown, the test just fails.

**How to test such a behavior in our setup?**

To add more on the discussion, ws.getData is basically a getter for our WebsocketSubject:

```
public getData(): ReconnectWebsocketSubject<any> {
  return this.ws;
}
```

and our WebsocketSubject:

```
connect(): void {
    this.socket = new WebSocketSubject(this.wsSubjectConfig);
    this.socket.subscribe(
      m => {
        this.next(m);
      },
      (error: Event) => {
        if (!this.socket) {
          this.reconnect();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  reconnect(): void {
    this.reconnectionObservable = interval(this.reconnectInterval).pipe(
      takeWhile((v, index) => {
        return index < this.reconnectAttempts && !this.socket;
      }),
    );

    this.reconnectionObservable.subscribe(
      () => {
        this.connect();
      },
      null,
      () => {
        this.reconnectionObservable = null;
        if (!this.socket) {
          this.error(new WebsocketReconnectFailureError());

          this.complete();
          this.connectionObserver.complete();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: what's your rxjs version?

Comment: RXJS version is 5.5.10

Comment: I'd say the problem is in the code you're testing. Rethrowing an error inside a subscriber doesn't make much sense and results in unhandled error.

Comment: hum and how then throw the error I want in a proper way? If I throw on the websocket itself, then the problem persists to test my overlay is true. I tried many refactor with no success :|

Comment: @BlackHoleGalaxy It depends on how why you throw this error there. An error is thrown to be caught elsewhere or result in uncaught exception that will stall the program. Neither of these things will happen in case of  `throw new WebsocketReconnectFailureError()`. Second `subscribe` callback exists to handle errors, not to throw them.

Comment: I got an ErrorHandler which extends the Angular ErrorHandler. To catch the errors and depending on which error is throw, redirect the user to proper page and log it on Sentry.

Comment: @BlackHoleGalaxy Again, `throw new WebsocketReconnectFailureError()` in `subscribe` cannot be caught anywhere and doesn't make sense. It's asynchronous error that isn't supposed to be caught by ErrorHandler. Consider using `@` because the participants don't receive notifications otherwise.

Comment: Understood. But I don't get where to place my throw. Just added our websocket subject to see where we could plug our throw correctly.

Comment: moved error on the subject itself. Still no way to test the overlay with success.